# Rails: Cucumber not cleaning DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, spork

I'm having some issues with cucumber & database transactions - specifically, when I run the test suite, database transactions are not cleaned afterwards.

I'm running rails 3.1 with spork, postgres.

Initially features/support/env.rb was set to use database_cleaner, but consistently got the following error on each call to the db:

> No database specified. Missing argument: database. (ArgumentError)
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:22:in `postgresql_connection'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in`new_connection'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:302:in `checkout_new_connection'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:254:in`block (2 levels) in checkout'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:250:in `loop'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:250:in`block in checkout'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:249:in`checkout'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:151:in `connection'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:388:in`retrieve_connection'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:107:in `retrieve_connection'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/cucumber-rails-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/rails/hooks/active_record.rb:7:in`connection'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/transaction.rb:17:in `clean'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:77:in`clean'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:56:in `block in clean'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:56:in`each'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:56:in `clean'
>         /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/cucumber-rails-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/rails/hooks/database_cleaner.rb:9:in`After'

I tried reverting to regular transactions, but no joy. I can access the database via the console (cucumber environment) and create/delete/retrieve records with no problems. The config/database.yml, features/support/env.rb, config/environments/cucumber.rb and rspec/spec_helper.rb files are added below. Any suggestions very appreciated - this one has had me stumped for some time:

CONFIG/DATABASE.yml

```
default: &defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  username: rails_dev
  password: foobar

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: fcct_d

test: &test
  <<: *defaults
  database: fcct_t

production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: fcct_p
  username: fcct
  password: k#1*5Avb3dTa

cucumber:
  adapter: postgresql
  username: rails_dev
  password: foobar
  database: fcct_t
```

FEATURES/SUPPORT/ENV.RB

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  require 'cucumber/rails'
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'


  Capybara.default_selector = :css

  ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

  begin
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  rescue NameError
    raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
  end

end

Spork.each_run do
  require 'factory_girl'
  require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../lib/existing_factory/existing_factory.rb')
end
```

CONFIG/ENVIRONMENTS/CUCUMBER.RB

> BusinessschoolCorporate::Application.configure do   # Settings
>   specified here will take precedence over those in
>   config/application.rb
>
> # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
>
> ## test suite.  You never need to work with it otherwise.  Remember
>
> that   # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and
>   is wiped   # and recreated between test runs.  Don't rely on the data
>   there!
>   config.cache_classes = true
>   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
>
> # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for
>   performance   config.serve_static_assets = true
>   config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
>
> # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil
>   config.whiny_nils = true
>
> # Show full error reports and disable caching
>   config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
>   config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
>
> # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
>   config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
>
> # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
>   config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false
>
> # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.   #
>   The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the   #
>   ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
>   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
>
> # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the
>   test database.   # This is necessary if your schema can't be
>   completely dumped by the schema dumper,   # like if you have
>   constraints or database-specific column types   #
>   config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
>
> # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
>   config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr end

SPEC/SPEC_HELPER.RB

> require 'rubygems' require 'spork'
>
> Spork.prefork do   # Loading more in this block will cause your tests
>   to run faster. However,   # if you change any configuration or code
>   from libraries loaded here, you'll   # need to restart spork for it
>   take effect.   # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails
>   generate rspec:install'   ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'   require
>   File.expand_path("../../config/environment", **FILE**)   require
>   'rspec/rails'
>
> # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros,
>   etc,   # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
>   Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
>
> RSpec.configure do |config|
>       # == Mock Framework
>       #
>       # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the
>   appropriate line:
>       #
>       # config.mock_with :mocha
>       # config.mock_with :flexmock
>       # config.mock_with :rr
>       config.mock_with :rspec
>
> ```
> # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or
> ```
>
> ActiveRecord fixtures
>       # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
>
> ```
> # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run
> ```
>
> each of your
>       # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or
>   assign false
>       # instead of true.
>       config.use_transactional_fixtures = true   end
>
> end
>
> Spork.each_run do   # This code will be run each time you run your
>   specs.
>
> end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering - it was the fact that I had &defaults in my config/database.yml file. Database cleaner has a 'defaults' call of its own, which intercepts the config info.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try putting `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in your `CONFIG/ENVIRONMENTS/CUCUMBER.RB` file?

Comment: Hi Sebastian - thanks for the response. Transactional fixtures were set as true, changed them to see if I could diagnose the error (have corrected above). Unfortunately, same problem. Thanks anyhow