# Active Record not deleting data in cucumber feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, rails-activerecord

Facing a weird problem. In the following code `Log` is an active record table. This method is called within a cucumber feature.

This method does not throw any error. But it does not clear the table as expected. Any possible mistake that I might be making?

```
def clear_db
    puts "Before Delete - Count => #{Log.count}" 
    # Outputs 1 which correspons to db count

    Log.delete_all

    puts "After Delete - Count => #{Log.count}" 
    # Outputs 0, but the db still has the record in the table
 end
```

Note: I have set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in rails_helper file

Comment: This question might be related to your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144112/rails-cucumber-not-cleaning-db

Comment: @RodrigoVasconcelos Thanks, but that does't help.

Comment: *"the db still has the record in the table"* -- Can you please clarify this point? I don't see anything wrong with your code, and it appears to be working as expected. I suspect you have a misunderstanding about *which* database the tests are using, and which database you are looking at when you say data is not deleted.

Comment: As @RodrigoVasconcelos hinted at above, I suspect you are deleting from the **test** database, then seeing records in the **development** database. Or, perhaps *something else* is creating records elsewhere in the code???

Comment: @TomLord I am testing with just one record in the Log table. I tried running the method `clear_db` multiple times. Getting the same result everytime. The count is "1" at the start of the method, count becomes "0" at the end, but the tbale still has the data.

Comment: @Muthukumar What **exactly** are you doing? Can I see the exact code you are running, and how you are running it? (Please can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48805525/edit) to provide a [mcve]?)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `databasecleaner` gem was present in the gemfile, though it was not used in the project. I guess `cucumber` uses this database cleaner gem by default and thus was mingling with my queries.

Removing `databasecleaner` gem from the gemfile solved the issue.